# Alterar elemento gerado através do evento de um elemento já pronto

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Tenho o seguinte código HTML:

```
    <div class="header">
        <ul class="navigation">
           <li><a>Home</a></li>
           <li><a id="limpar">Limpar</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="centro">

    </div>
```

E javascript:

```
$(window).load(function() {
   for (i = 1; i <= 2000; i++) 
   {
       $('.centro').append("<div class='bloco' onclick='changeColor(this)'> </div>");
   }
})

function changeColor(x) {
  if(x.style.background == "purple")
  {
     x.style.background = "white";
     x.style.color = "black";
  }
  else
  {
     x.style.background = "purple";
     x.style.color = "white";
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {  
   $("#limpar").click(function(){
      bloco.style.background = "white";
   });
});
```

Quando clico no botão limpar recebo o seguinte erro:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: bloco is not defined
```

Comment: Isso é porque a sua variável `bloco` não está definida antes de querer mudar a cor do background, O que é esse bloco? Corresponde a que a que elemento no HTML?

Comment: Acho que em vez de `bloco.style.background = "white";` queres ter `$('.bloco').css('background', "white");` será isso?

Comment: @Sergio Muito obrigado, isso resolveu meu problema. Imaginava que fosse algum problema diferente xD

Comment: @RaulTomaz ótimo! Se quiseres podes marcar a resposta como aceite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esse(s) elemento(s) que estás a adicionar `<div class='bloco' ...` podem ser selecionados através da sua classe com jQuery usando `$('.bloco')`. Com jQuery, para mudar o `.style` usa-se `.css()`. Assim podes mudar esse `background` trocando:

```
bloco.style.background = "white";
```

por

```
$('.bloco').css('background', "white");
```